# Detail information of Pagination in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, search, gridview

I have a gridview whose data's are coming from the database. I also want to show the paging in the gridview. I want the paging as below mentioned in the image.

[Image](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=414168935103). As I have no idea from where to start this, can you let me know any helpful links So that I can start developing it. Also please see the code for your reference:-

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdCSRPageData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="grdCSRPageData_DataBound" PageSize="5" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="grdCSRPageData_RowCommand">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="30">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_title" HeaderText="Page Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="page_description" HeaderText="Page Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_title" HeaderText="Meta Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_keywords" HeaderText="Meta Keywords" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="meta_description" HeaderText="Meta Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" Width="15" Height="15" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="DeleteRow" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Id") %>" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?');" />
                            </span>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Right now, I have only this much of code for PageIndexChanging, if you need anything else let me know

```
  protected void grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdCSRPageData.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdCSRPageData.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write C# code on event '`grdCSRPageData_PageIndexChanging`' same as 'grdCSRPageData_DataBound'

Comment: Yes, I know that. Any start related to this?

Comment: can you give your c# section also ?

Comment: So now you will get paging ?

Comment: Yes paging is working, but I want also the information as I stated in the image

Comment: do you want change style of page index ?

Comment: I want the deatil paging information as mentioned in the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65565/discussion-between-rashid-and-nadeem-khan).

Comment: Thanks Rashid, for the link.Applied it and it helped me